# Generate bigrams BUT only noun and verb combinations

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have some code below that generates bigrams for my data frame column.

```
import nltk
import collections
counts = collections.Counter()
for sent in df["message"]:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    counts.update(nltk.bigrams(words))
counts = {k: v for k, v in counts.items() if v > 25}
```

This works great for generating my most common bigrams in the 'message' column of my dataframe, BUT, I want to get bigrams that contain one verb and one noun per pair of bigrams only.

Any help doing this with spaCy or nltk would be appreciated!

Comment: An example would be great.

Comment: @acodejdatam do you mean N, V and V, N bi-grams?

Comment: @ongenz, yes.  I only want noun verbs and verb noun bigrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `spaCy`, you have access to pre-trained [models](https://spacy.io/usage/models) in various languages. You can install them like so: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Then, you can easily run something like this to do custom filtering:

```
import spacy

text = "The sleeping cat thought that sitting in the couch resting would be a great idea."
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(text)
for i in range(len(doc)):
    j = i+1
    if j < len(doc):
        if (doc[i].pos_ == "NOUN" and doc[j].pos_ == "VERB") or (doc[i].pos_ == "VERB" and doc[j].pos_ == "NOUN"):
            print(doc[i].text, doc[j].text, doc[i].pos_, doc[j].pos_)
```

which will output

> sleeping cat VERB NOUN
>
> cat thought NOUN VERB
>
> couch resting NOUN VERB

Comment: Thanks for the help!  How would I run this over a dataframe column of text with spaCy instead of just a text string?

Comment: Welcome! To efficiently run `spaCy` on large volumes of text, use `nlp.pipe(texts)` - see here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing

Comment: Sofie VL can you provide an example of this code with a dataframe.  Say I have one column of my dataframe that is text.  Each row is a sentence.  How do I run this code over that?  I couldn't figure it out with the documentation.

Comment: You'll have to extract the text out of your column first, ofcourse. Something like `text = df["message"]`. That is not a part of the spaCy library, but preprocessing that needs to happen on your end...

Answer (score 1):

You have to first apply pos_tag and then bigrams

You can try like this

```
import nltk

sent = 'The thieves stole the paintings'
token_sent = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
tagged_sent = nltk.pos_tag(token_sent)

word_tag_pairs = nltk.bigrams(tagged_sent)

##Apply conditions according to your requirement to filter the bigrams

print([(a,b) for a, b in word_tag_pairs if a[1].startswith('N') and b[1].startswith('V')])
```

It just gives an output of

```
[(('thieves', 'NNS'), ('stole', 'VBD'))]
```